# Getting insight into partitions of a table in Azure Synapse (similar to SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, performance, partitioning, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse-analytics

I'm using [Dedicated SQL-Pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-overview-what-is) AKA Azure Synapse (which is different from serverless/on-demand Synapse that comes with Azure Synapse Analytics). And [According to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-partition):

> While the syntax of partitioning may be slightly different from SQL Server, the basic concepts are the same.

- I have a table that receives ~33 million new rows per day.
- Column named `version` indicates the day on which that row arrived. E.g. all 33 million rows arriving on `2021-05-22` have same `version` value (`2021-05-22`).
- Currently it has ~300 million rows (9 days worth of data).
- Table has daily partitions.

Here is the order of things I did:

- create table with 345 daily partitions (from 22-May-2021 to 30-Apr-2022).
- insert 9 days (33 million x 9 = ~300 million rows) worth of data into this table. I used `INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM some_other_table_with_300_million_rows`)
- update statistics mytable

**Question**

- Expectation: I have 9 partitions with ~33 million rows and 336 partitions with 0 rows.
- Reality: All partitions have equal amount of data.

When I run [this SQL statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-partitions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT 
    partition_id, index_id, partition_number, rows, data_compression_desc 
FROM 
    sys.partitions 
WHERE 
    object_id = OBJECT_ID('mytable')
```

I get this result:

```
partition_id        index_id    partition_number    rows    data_compression_desc
72057597508452352   1           1                   868784  COLUMNSTORE
72057597508583424   1           2                   868784  COLUMNSTORE
......
72057597553410048   1           344                 868784  COLUMNSTORE
72057597553541120   1           345                 868812  COLUMNSTORE
```

868784 * 345 = ~300 million

[This SQL statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-partition-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) however:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_pdw_nodes_db_partition_stats 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('mytable')
```

returns no rows.

---

Originally posted here until I discovered dba community: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67824876/getting-insight-into-partitions-of-a-table-in-azure-synapse-similar-to-sql-serv